# MethodError calling constructor of parametric struct

Tags: struct, julia

I'm trying to create a linked list in Julia.
I have:

```
mutable struct LLNode{T}
    x::T
    next::Union{LLNode{T},Void}
    prev::Union{LLNode{T},Void}
end

mutable struct LinkedList{T}
   count::Int
   head::Union{LLNode{T},Void}
   tail::Union{LLNode{T},Void}
end
```

Now, the above code compiles fine. I can also run:`x = LLNode(0,nothing,nothing)` fine. But when I run `y = LinkedList(0,nothing,nothing)` I get a `no method matching LinkedList(::Int64, ::Void, ::Void)` error. What gives?

`VERSION` returns `v"0.6.2"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `LLNode(0,nothing,nothing)`, Julia is able to figure out that it needs to construct an `LLNode{Int}` based upon the type of the first argument.  But in `LinkedList(0, nothing, nothing)`, there's quite literally nothing for it to go on to determine what the type parameter should be, so it doesn't know what to construct.

Instead, you either need to explicitly choose what you want `T` to be:

```
julia> LinkedList{Int}(0, nothing, nothing)
LinkedList{Int64}(0, nothing, nothing)
```

or it can get the `T` based upon a not-nothing argument:

```
julia> LinkedList(0, LLNode(0, nothing, nothing), nothing)
LinkedList{Int64}(0, LLNode{Int64}(0, nothing, nothing), nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `LinkedList` requires parameter `T`. If you pass `nothing` as second and third argument there is no way for Julia to infer what `T` is.

Therefore you either have to explicitly specify it, e.g.:

```
julia> LinkedList{Int}(0, nothing, nothing)
LinkedList{Int64}(0, nothing, nothing)
```

or pass a second and/or third argument allowing to infer `T`, e.g. using your `x`:

```
julia> LinkedList(0, x, x)
LinkedList{Int64}(0, LLNode{Int64}(0, nothing, nothing), LLNode{Int64}(0, nothing, nothing))
```

As a side note --- you might want to check out https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/LinkedLists.jl for an example of a fairly complete implementation of linked list.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It proved to have plenty of helpful (and idiomatic!) examples of dealing with parametric structs. I suggest this [reference](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods-1) in conjunction with your link for any other beginners out there who want to learn about parametric structs.